# Parsing PDF to extract Abstract

Tags: python, parsing, pdf, abstract

I'm trying to get a python script that allows me to automatically retrieve an abstract from any PDF, as long as it contains one.
Some people would have an idea how to write an automated python script already, requiring only the input file, that would allow me to extract the abstract from that PDF?

Here is what I have already obtained. This script is not automated since it requires a specific word to delimit the text to extract...

```
pdfFileObj = open('3D Printing in Pharmaceutical Sector: An Overview.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
num_pages = pdfReader.numPages      
count = 0
pagecontent = ""                                                   
while count < num_pages: #The while loop will read each page
    #print(count)
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(count)
    count +=1
    pagecontent += pageObj.extractText()


def between(value, a, b):
    # Find and validate before-part.
    pos_a = value.find(a)
    if pos_a == -1: return ""
    # Find and validate after part.
    pos_b = value.rfind(b)
    if pos_b == -1: return ""
    # Return middle part.
    adjusted_pos_a = pos_a + len(a)
    if adjusted_pos_a >= pos_b: return ""
    return value[adjusted_pos_a:pos_b]

desired = between(pagecontent,"Abstract","Keywords")
print('The abstract of the document is :' + desired)

text = desired.encode('ascii','ignore').lower() # It returns an utf-8 encoded version of the string & Lowercasing each word
text = text.decode('ISO-8859-1')
keywords = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]\w+',text)
```

Comment: By you saying `Some people would have an automated python script already`, are you asking if anyone here already has a script that does what you want? I'm not sure if that's considered an on-topic post according to this site's guidelines (as laid out in the [tour], the [ask] page, and this [help/on-topic] topic).

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30904755/extract-abstract-full-text-from-scientific-literature-given-doi-or-title

Comment: You may want to look into CERMINE: [website](http://cermine.ceon.pl/index.html), [github](https://github.com/CeON/CERMINE).