# Extracting full-text research papers

Tags: python, web-scraping, nlp

I am working on an NLP project which deals with full-text research papers. I have a list of DOIs and I want to store all the text of these research papers in one .txt file. Currently, I am downloading the pdfs from scihub, and then extracting text from these pdfs. But, this is very slow, especially when I have a lot of papers. Are there better alternatives?

At a high-level, this is how I get the text for one paper:

```
!python -m PyPaperBot --doi="10.2196/29324" --dwn-dir="C:\"
```

and then

```
with fitz.open("sample.pdf") as doc:
    text = ""
    for page in doc:
        text += page.get_text()
```

I took a look at some related questions ([Extract abstract / full text from scientific literature given DOI or Title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30904755/extract-abstract-full-text-from-scientific-literature-given-doi-or-title)), but they seem very outdated. I've also looked into PubMedCentral, but it has a smaller database of research papers than sci-hub.

Comment: I would use cloud server or sort and do that work in parallel.  This way you can speed up as fast as possible.  And it won't cost that much, I suppose.

Comment: How many DOIs do you have?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did in your case (I work on Ubuntu):

I split my list of DOIs in chunks of 1000 DOIs and then built a bash script that started to download these chunks in parallel. Here an example when having 3000 DOIs:

```
#!/bin/bash
python -m PyPaperBot --doi-file="/dois_chunk_1.txt" --dwn-dir="papers_chunk_1/" &
python -m PyPaperBot --doi-file="/dois_chunk_2.txt" --dwn-dir="papers_chunk_2/" &
python -m PyPaperBot --doi-file="/dois_chunk_3.txt" --dwn-dir="papers_chunk_3/" &
wait
```

The &-symbol ensures that the commands are executed in parallel. The wait-command ensures that your programm stops only if all other commands are finished.